# Audible alarm for iPod Touch low battery

Tags: ipod, alarm

I'd like my iPod Touch to play an alarm sound whenever the battery is low (for example, 10% power remaining). Is it possible to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately not. The battery warnings are fixed system behaviour, and not configurable by the user currently.